# Firebase Web creating user and write data in Real time database not working correct

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im assuming a strange behaviour while creating an account. I don't have an error to show, but sometimes firebase is not creating the user, sometimes firebase creates the user, but it **not** writes any data in realtime database. Pls someone help me out..

```
function signUp() {

  var userArtistName = document.getElementById("userArtistName").value;
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
  var userPassword = document.getElementById("userPassword").value;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).then((success) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
    }
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var userData = {
      userArtistName: userArtistName,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userIsArtist: true,
      userId: uid,
    }
    firebaseRef.child('users/' + uid).set(userData);
    console.log('User successfully created!');
    // code for replace user
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
}
```

my html form:

```
<form action="#">
    <h1>Hello Form</h1>
    <span>Register now</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="userArtistName"/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="userEmail" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="userPassword" />
    <button onclick="signUp()">Registrieren</button>
</form>
```

fb rules:

[image]

My firebase.js file:

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    //fb config here
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to firebase authenthification
const auth = firebase.auth();



function signUp() {

  var userArtistName = document.getElementById("userArtistName").value;
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
  var userPassword = document.getElementById("userPassword").value;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).then((success) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
    }
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var userData = {
      userArtistName: userArtistName,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userIsArtist: true,
      userId: uid,
    }
    firebaseRef.child('users/' + uid).set(userData);
    console.log('User successfully created!');
    // code for replace user
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
}





function signIn() {

  var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
  var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword");

  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
    .then(userCredential => {
      const userId = userCredential.user.uid;
      return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value')
    })
    .then(snapshot => {
      var userIsArtist = snapshot.val().userIsArtist;
      if (!userIsArtist) {
        //Redirect to login or other action or message
        //signOut();
        console.log(userIsArtist);

      } else {
        window.location.replace("main.html");
      }});
    // }).catch((error) => {
    //   // Handle Errors here.
    //   // .catch function to hide error in console. error tells UID actually. We don't want that
    //   var errorCode = error.code;
    //   var errorMessage = error.message;
    // });
}





function signOut() {
  auth.signOut()
  console.log('Successfully signed out!');
  window.location.replace('login.html');
}



auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {

    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(user != null){
      // deactivating loading spinner for people, who are not logged in
      document.getElementById("login-cover").style.display = "none";
    } 



    var email = user.email;

    document.getElementById('fb-email').innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email;
    console.log('Successfully logged in! ---- Active User: ' + email);

  } else if (
    // Not signed in, redirecting to login page
    user == null &&
    window.location.href == 'http://localhost/www.muego.com/main.html' ||
    window.location.href == 'http://localhost/www.muego.com/songs.html') {
    // Redirect user because session is not valid anymore

    window.location.replace('login.html');
  }

});



function resetPassword() {

  var auth = firebase.auth();
  var emailAddress = "admin@trash-mail.com";

  auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function () {
    // Email sent.
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // An error happened.
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a Screenshot of your Firebase Database security rules?

Comment: yes of course, I edited my question with the image.

Comment: What error are you gettin?? And are you sure that the user is logged in while doing this?

Comment: okay i checked the code and im not getting any errors, but I can see some strange behaviour with the button. so the url ist `example.com/login.html`, now when i fill in the values and press register, page is reloading and url changes to `example.com/login.html?#`. If i then fill in the values again, it works.. its this form right here, only difference is I have onclick function on signup button. https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/full/vPKWjd do you have an idea whats causing this?

Comment: Do i have to reset something maybe? i really dont have any idea.. i tried it again right now, the user gets created but it didnt write data in the real time database..

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it works the second time and not first... by the way you have `onclick="createAccount"` but you have provided me code of `signup()`. Please post code of the function `createAccount()3`

Comment: Many thanks that you are taking time for this. Oh thats my fault, its the same function. just copyed out of an earlier version. i corrected it in the main thread.

Comment: Try putting all the code into the `if(user != null) {. . .}` Maybe because the first time it may have perceived that user isn't logged in or so .. can you try it ??

Comment: the user might be null brh.. you need to login that user instantly after creation using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`.. [check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)

Comment: @Dharmaraj im pretty new to firebase and javascript and unsure if I can manage it. I posted my javascript file, this is all the firebase code where I manage stuff. Can you see something right there?

Comment: Moving this to chat.. we can have discussion there....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214962/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-marcel-dz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after several hours of try and error and with much love and help of @Dharmaraj the final code looks like this:

```
  function createAccount(){

    var userEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
    var userPass = document.getElementById("userPassword").value;
    var userArtistName = document.getElementById("userArtist").value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).then(function() {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      console.log(user);
      var uid;
      if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid;
        console.log(uid)
        var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
        var userData = {
          userArtistName: userArtistName,
          userEmail: userEmail,
          userIsArtist: true,
          userId: uid,
        }
        firebaseRef.child('users/' + uid).set(userData).then(() => {
          window.location.replace('main.html');
        }).catch();
        console.log('User successfully created!' + 'logged in as:' + userEmail);
    }})
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });

  }
```

There where alot of issues  with the redirect actually, so now I placed the replace itself in the promise of the `firebaseRef.child` **and not** the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` . This made it work!